# Using RestKit to map Login Responses

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, restkit

Been working with RestKit for a while now, but I am running into a difficult problem with ObjectMapping.  I have a login API that requires me to post two key values as follows:

```
 {"fb_access_token":"123456789.....",
 "fb_user_id":"1234..."}
```

It returns:

```
 {"message":"logged in"}
```

I created the following classes to map the POST submission and the response in the following gist:

https://gist.github.com/2764803

I can post and login without mapping the response as in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/2764823

What is the best way to map a post and response like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use RKObjectManager instead of RKClient in order to make proper use of the elegant object mapping mechanisms. All you need is explained in this [RestKit wiki page](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping). If you have further questions after reading, please ask away.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  I had tried that as in this gist:
https://gist.github.com/2772399

Comment: Then I post it using the RKObjectManager as seen here:
https://gist.github.com/2772414

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this

[Making a post to API with RKParams and mapping the response with RKObjectMapping using RestKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760333/making-a-post-to-api-with-rkparams-and-mapping-the-response-with-rkobjectmapping/)

I tried the solution posted here but it didn't work so well for me.