# Making a post to API with RKParams and mapping the response with RKObjectMapping using RestKit

Tags: objective-c, api, restkit, block

Right now I'm doing a huge refactory to my code and I want to unify the way I'm using Restkit. I had separated ways of making RPC calls to my API server and REST calls.

REST calls where made using objectMapping and RPC calls where made with the RKClient. Besides that, I'm using blocks instead of delegates, which is great but I have some doubts about how it works.

Here is the code I had before, which worked nicely to post the object and do the mapping manually using delegates and after that is the new code using blocks that does not send the params.

```
//This was the old way...
- (void) upload: (KFMedia *) pic {

    RKParams* imageParams = [RKParams params];
    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pic.image, 0.7f);
    [imageParams setData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/jpg" forParam:@"FileUpload"];

    [[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/api/upload/" params:imageParams delegate:self]; 

}

//This is the new way I'm trying...
- (void) upload: (KFMedia *) pic onLoad:(RKObjectLoaderDidLoadObjectBlock) loadBlock onError:(RKRequestDidFailLoadWithErrorBlock)failBlock{

    RKParams* imageParams = [RKParams params];
    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pic.image, 0.7f);
    [imageParams setData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/jpg" forParam:@"FileUpload"];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/api/upload/" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {

        //Trying to set params here, but it seems that I'm not sending anything :(
        loader.params = imageParams;
        loader.objectMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[KFMedia class]];
        loader.delegate = self;
        loader.onDidLoadObject = loadBlock;
        loader.onDidFailWithError = failBlock;
        loader.onDidFailLoadWithError = failBlock;
        loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {
            [self fireErrorBlock:failBlock onErrorInResponse:response];
        };

    }];

}
```

The request I'm sending has its body empty, that means that the params are not being sendend or setted properly. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem. To send the extra params with loadObjectsAtResourcePath you must force a post using

```
loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
```

the code is as follows:

```
- (void) upload: (KFMedia *) pic onLoad:(RKObjectLoaderDidLoadObjectBlock) loadBlock onError:(RKRequestDidFailLoadWithErrorBlock)failBlock{

    RKParams* imageParams = [RKParams params];
    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pic.image, 0.7f);
    [imageParams setData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/jpg" forParam:@"FileUpload"];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/api/upload/" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {

        loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST; //This line solved the problem
        loader.params = imageParams;
        loader.objectMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[KFMedia class]];
        loader.delegate = self;
        loader.onDidLoadObject = loadBlock;
        loader.onDidFailWithError = failBlock;
        loader.onDidFailLoadWithError = failBlock;
        loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {
            [self fireErrorBlock:failBlock onErrorInResponse:response];
        };

    }];

}
```